# Клавиатура ReplyKeyboardMarkup(aiogram) отображается только в приложении на Android, в десктопной версии и на устройствах Apple клавиатуры нет

Tags: python, aiogram, клавиатура

Бот отправляет клавиатуру с сообщением в топике(может это важно?).
Вот код хэндлера.

```py
async def car_driver(message: types.Message, state: FSMContext):
    """Обработка введеных вариантов машин и цен."""
    check = message.text.split('/')
    if len(check) == 2 and check[1].isdigit() and len(check[0]) < 24:
        async with state.proxy() as data:
            data['count'] = data['count'] + 1
            data[data['count']] = f'{check[0]} {check[1]}'
        await message.reply(
            'Введите еще автомобиль и цену поездки либо нажмите кнопку '
            '"Закончить ввод авто "', reply_markup=kb.auto_input)
    elif len(check) == 2 and check[1].isdigit():
        await message.reply(
            'Очень длинное название. Введите не более 23 символов!')
    else:
        await message.reply(
            'Вы ввели данные в неверном формате!\n'
            'Введите автомобиль и цену поездки в следующем формате\n\n'
            '<b>Автомобиль</b>/<b>цена поездки(цифры)</b>')
```

Вот код клавиатуры

```py
auto_input1 = KeyboardButton('Закончить ввод авто ')
auto_input = ReplyKeyboardMarkup(
    resize_keyboard=True)
auto_input.add(auto_input1)
```

Скрины с Android и десктопной версии прилагаются.

Гугл и Chat GPT не помогли, может кто сталкивался с подобной проблемой??[image: Android]
[image: Десктоп]

Comment: "Скрины с Android и десктопной версии прилагаются." Вы добавили скрин только с `Andoird`-а.

Comment: Добавил скрин с десктопной версии.